# python import location from one def to another def to print location from weather API

Tags: python, api, tkinter, location, weather

```
def location():
    res = requests.get('https://ipinfo.io/')
    data = res.json()
    stad = data['city']
    location = data['loc'].split('.')
    latitude = location[0]
    longitude = location[1]
    return stad

def get_weather():
    location(stad)
    weather_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather'
    # q=Amsterdam&appid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    city = location(stad)
    params = {'q': city, 'APPID': weather_key, 'units': 'metric'}
    response = requests.get(url, params= params)
    print(f'Het weer vandaag in Utrecht is:')
    print(response.json())
```

Dear stackoverflow users,

I try to get my from city = location(stad) from def location() ((stad means city in dutch))

but it doesnt work python says location(stad) is not defined what can i do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`location(stad)` is not defined, because "location" is a function that does not receive parameters.

You have to write:
`city = location()`, then the variable "stad" that calculated in the function "location" will assign to your var "city". Is it clear?

In addition, the line :

```
location(stad)
```

(at the beginning of the function `get_weather()` )
looks like unnecessary line. why to call the function, if you do not use what was returned?

Answer (score 0):

You mishandled the function response. Instead of assigning the response into a variable, you have passed a parameter (Undefined variable) to the function "location".

Instead of `location(stad)`, you have to use `stad = location()`.

Also, there are few things I saw in your code which might be unnecessary -

In "location" definition, since you are returning only the city(stad), you do not  have to process the longitude and latitude. Also, since longitude/latitudes can be in decimals, you may not get exact values if you split using "period"(`.`).